# How to fetch data when DynamoDB multiple Global Secondary Indexes (GSI) hashed with the same key?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDb table below for creating country-based leaderboards for two different score types. I wanted to create two GSI tables based on the same partition-key field but with different sort keys. I am using [boostchicken's](https://github.com/boostchicken/spring-data-dynamodb) (forked from [derjust](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb)) spring-data-library as jpa.

**My libraries:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.504</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.boostchicken</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

**My table and gsi's:**

```
Player
-----------------------------
Partition Key   -  PlayerId
Attribute       -  ScoreType1
Attribute       -  ScoreType2
Attribute       -  IsoCountryCode

GSI-1
------------------------------
Partition Key   - Country
Sort Key        - ScoreType1
Attribute       - PlayerId  

GSI-2
------------------------------
Partition Key   - Country
Sort Key        - ScoreType2
Attribute       - PlayerId
```

---

I wrote **entity class** by giving both GSI's names into `globalSecondaryIndexNames`:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Player")
  public class PlayerDynamoEntity {
  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "PlayerId")
  private String player;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "CountryCode")
  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "CountryCode",
          globalSecondaryIndexNames = {"GSI-1", "GSI-2"})
  private String countryCode;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Score-1")
  @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "Score-1", globalSecondaryIndexName = "GSI-1")
  private String score1;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Score-2")
  @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "Score-2", globalSecondaryIndexName = "GSI-2")
  private String score2;
```

---

**and my repository:**

```
@EnableScan
public interface PlayerRepository extends CrudRepository<PlayerDynamoEntity, String> {
  Page<PlayerDynamoEntity> findByCountryCode(String countryCode, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Hence the countryCode is the hash for both GSI tables, Whenever I write ***ByCountryCode it automatically behaves like I only query for GSI-1. How can I access the second GSI table?

I expected to specify the GSI somehow but I couldn't find it.
I have tried adding methods such as findByCountryCodeOrderByScoreType2Desc in the repository interface, but it didn't work.

Comment: In the Mapper which is being used under the hood, you can explicitly `setIndexName`. If the forked repo can't do it, then I suggest trying a condition on the sort key, `Score2 > -1` for example. Although your scores are strings so be sure it's lexicographically correct.

Comment: @AdesojiAlu actually it has worked! Thx for contrubitouon. I think you should put it as an answer.

Comment: @AhmetOrhan i have done it